# How to get github-action Tkinter version >= 8.6 [MACOS]?

Tags: python, tkinter, github-actions

I'm trying to install `ttkthemes`, which depends on Tkinter >= 8.6.

I have the following minimal working example to show the issue:

```
jobs:
  demo:
    # I have also tried macOS-11 here, the same result
    runs-on: macOS-latest

    steps:
      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2.2.2
        with:
          #Tried 3.8 here as well
          python-version: 3.9
        
      - name: Show TKinter version
        run: |
          python3 -c 'import tkinter; tcl = tkinter.Tcl(); print(tcl.call("info", "patchlevel"))'
```

So far, I've tried countless approaches:

- `brew install tcl-tk`: Useless, its already installed and reinstallation doesn't change anything
- `brew reinstall python`
- `brew install python-tk@3.9`

I just can't get it to work, and would highly appreciate any input!

Comment: Did you try installing Python 3.9 for MacOS from `python.org`?

Comment: i think i did, but maybe how would you do that exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Mac machine.

Comment: its working on my mac, the question is about github actions